# WAMP: how can i measure the bandwidth usage?

Tags: localhost, wamp, bandwidth, measure

is there a module or program to measure how many bandwidth my localhost is using and that be able to visualize that information through a chart or something?

---

**Edit:**

But im talking more on the way that online servers do, they show you the entire information about the hard disk you use, and how much bandwidth you are using including what days were the most important, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the build in Resource Monitor in Windows.

- Click the *Start* button
- Type in the search box:

> Resource Monitor

- Click the *Network* tab
- You should see the *httpd.exe* Image on the left.  This is your Wamp server.

If you view your localhost in a browser you should see the Network Activity change for *httpd.exe*.